# How can I use imaplib to extract email headers and print them into a text file?

Tags: python, email, imaplib

I am able to connect to Gmail using the following code:

```
import imaplib
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
mail.login('myusername@gmail.com', 'mypassword')
mail.list()
```

I now need to select "All Mail" from the account.

```
mail.select("All Mail")
```

But I do not believe this is working.

Then I reach the very tricky part for me: I want to be able to download all headers for all emails to either a .txt file or .mbox file. I have looked around and no questions/answers provide a way to save a local copy of the headers. Any ideas?

Comment: See [Gmail IMAP extensions](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap_extensions#special-use_extension_of_the_list_command)

Answer (score 0):

If you do `mail.list()` it gives you list of all IMAP/Gmail folders. Something like this

```
('OK', ['(\\HasNoChildren) "/" "INBOX"', '(\\HasChildren \\Noselect) "/" "[Gmail]"', '(\\All \\HasNoChildren) "/" "[Gmail]/All Mail"', '(\\Drafts \\HasNoChildren) "/" "[Gmail]/Drafts"', '(\\HasNoChildren \\Important) "/" "[Gmail]/Important"', '(\\HasNoChildren \\Sent) "/" "[Gmail]/Sent Mail"', '(\\HasNoChildren \\Junk) "/" "[Gmail]/Spam"', '(\\Flagged \\HasNoChildren) "/" "[Gmail]/Starred"', '(\\HasNoChildren \\Trash) "/" "[Gmail]/Trash"'])
```

So to select all the mails you can do `mail.select('[Gmail]/All Mail')`.

```
import imaplib
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
mail.login('myusername@gmail.com', 'mypassword')
mail.select('[Gmail]/All Mail')

#Search for all UIDs first
result, data = mail.uid('search', None, 'ALL')
uids = data[0].split()

#Loop through each uid to fetch headers
for uid in uids:
    result, data = mail.uid('fetch',uid, '(RFC822.HEADER)')
    print data[0][1] #Headers will be stored here which can then be saved in a text file
```

Answer (score -1):

```
mail.select('"[Gmail]/Tous les messages"')
```

Comment: Can you explain why you post what seems a French version (i.e. wrong language for StackOverflow) of only a fragment of the solution from the existing answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/28448199/7733418 Are you trying to provide answer according to [answer]? Then please [edit] to make that more obvious.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).